# Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 on insertBefore

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

function add(identifier, html){
    var frag = create(html);
    document.body.insertBefore(frag, document.getElementById(identifier));
}
```

`identifier` is the string id of a tag that I've verified in developer tools exists, `html` is just the fragment I want to prepend to the element denoted by said `identifier`. `frag` is a bonefide html fragment, and the call to `getElementById` returns a bonefide element ie neither are strings. Why am I getting the above error on `insertBefore`?

Comment: No, I guess this is the issue? So the object insertBefore is called in needs to be a parent of the 2nd argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element might not be a direct children of `document.body`. Try this ->

```
function add(identifier, html){
    var frag = create(html),
        el = document.getElementById(identifier);
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(frag, el);
}
```